# Flexbox layout, 3 items 1 left 1 right 1 on second row

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Not quite sure how to put this want a layout that basically does this with divs

A                                    B
C

Where the contents of A are left justified, the contents of B are right justified, and the contents of C are left justified.

Understand the basics of Flex, but just can't seem to get my mind around achieving this. Guess A, B, C would be div containers, with flex wrap turned on to get C to the second line.

Hopefully this isn't too vague.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
section {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

div:nth-child(1) {
  flex: 1 0 45%;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

div:nth-child(2) {
  flex: 1 0 45%;
}

div:nth-child(3) {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

div {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  background-color: lightgray;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div>A</div>
  <div>B</div>
  <div>C</div>
</section>
```

Comment: When i replace 45% to 50% its shrink whole area ! ,but 60% and 30% okay for two column, So why its happen when two portion make 100% and then one portion nested in whole row?

Comment: Because 100% *plus* the 5px margin results in an overflow of the container. That's why I used less than 50% -- to accommodate the margin space.